# Returning a Character String from #define Function

Tags: c, string, function, c-preprocessor

I know you can return a character string from a normal function in **C** as in this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* returnstring(char *pointer) {
    pointer="dog";
    return pointer;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *dog = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", returnstring(dog));
}
```

However, I can't find a way to be able to return character strings in `#define` functions, as in this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define returnstring(pointer) { \
   pointer="dog"; \
   return pointer; \
}

int main(void)
{
    char *dog = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", returnstring(dog));
}
```

I know that there are workarounds(like using the first program). I just want to know if it is possible

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Don't make confusing, a macro function-like doesn't behave like a function.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about a "#define function" is, IMO, the wrong way to approach this.

#define is a blunt instrument which amounts to a text find/replace. It knows little to nothing about C++ as a language, and the replace is done before any of your real code is even looked at.

What you have written isn't a function in its own right, it is a piece of text that looks like one, and it put in where you have written the alias.

If you want to #define what you just did, that's fine (I didn't check your example specifically, but in general, using #define for a function call and substituting the arguments is possible), but think twice before doing so unless you have an amazing reason. And then think *again* until you decide not to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "return" from a macro. Your best (ugh... arguably the "best", but anyway) bet is to formulate your macro in such a way that it evaluates to the expression you want to be the result. For example:

```
#define returnstring(ptr) ((ptr) = "hello world")

const char *p;
printf("%s\n", returnstring(p));
```

If you have multiple expression statements, you can separate them using the horrible comma operator:

```
#define even_more_dangerous(ptr) (foo(), bar(), (ptr) = "hello world")
```

If you are using GCC or a compatible compiler, you can also take advantage of a GNU extension called "statement expressions" so as to embed whole (non-expression) statements into your macro:

```
#define this_should_be_a_function(ptr) ({ \
    if (foo) { \
        bar(); \
    } else { \
        for (int i = 0; i < baz(); i++) { \
            quirk(); \
        } \
    } \
    ptr[0]; // last statement must be an expression statement \
})
```

**But if you get to this point, you could really just write a proper function as well.**

Answer (score 0):

You don't return anything from a `#define`d macro. Roughly speaking, the C preprocessor replaces the macro call with the text of the macro body, with arguments textually substituted into their positions. If you want a macro to assign a pointer to `"dog"` and evaluate to the pointer, you can do this:

```
#define dogpointer(p) ((p)="dog")
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `returnstring` as a macro does not do what it says; it also assigns the value to the parameter. The function does as it says, even if it (somewhat oddly) uses its parameter as a temporary variable.

The function is equivalent to:

```
char* returnstring(char *ignored) {
    return "dog";
}
```

The function macro is much the same as:

```
 #define returnstring(pointer) pointer = "dog"
```

Which begs the question, why not call it `assign_string`?

Or why not just have:

```
  #define dogString "dog"
```

And write:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *dog = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", dog = dogString);
}
```

The function for assignString is:

```
char* assignstring(char **target{
    *target= "dog";
    return *target;
}
```

You can then have a macro:

```
assign_string_macro(pointer) assignstring(&pointer)
```

Ultimately if you want to "*return character strings in #define functions*", then all you need is:

```
#define returnstring(ignored) "dog"
```